# How to create a string map "location" and "location Value Text" of this string text?

Tags: html, string, typescript, dom, pattern-matching

I developed project using anguler with ngRx framework. I used TypeScript with HTML for developing front-end.My db have saved 'HTML' format texts like below.

```
 "<html><body><a href="C:\Users\K\Documents\docker_command.txt">A.txt </a>
               <a href="C:\Users\Documents\B.txt">B.txt </a>
               <a href="C:\Users\K\Documents\D.txt">D.txt </a>
               <a href="https:\\www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com </a>
  </body></html>"
```

This text priviouly , I drectly render in html file using `<dev INNERHTML ={{stringText }} \>` like wise.
But my project using JXBrowser and as it's  configuration , this can't be directly open in default browser clicking just link.

For that work ,I need to take href location as URL and when click it passed to .ts file.

I thought ,it change as like this `<a role="button" click='getLink(myText)'> {{getLink(value}} </a>'`. so ,create this ,I need that text put a array with contain 'location' and value.Next ,I though ,Iterate that array in HTML file.

I need some expert help to do this ? I am struggle with map above text to such kind of string array (eg :`array[hrfeLink][value])`. Hope some expert help me.

------------Updated---------------

According to the comment, I will try this way, and I can take the link location. But still couldn't take value.

```
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(info, "text/html");
  let x = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length ; i++) {
     console.log(x[i].getAttribute('href'));
  }
```

Comment: There's two approaches: you can use regular expressions to extract values from the HTML string, or you can [parse the HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) into a javascript Document.  I recommend parsing.

Comment: Can you ,please , give me an example , how can i use domParser. I will create let x =new DOMParser() object. and parser ->let doc = parser.parseFromString(stringHTML, "application/html") text like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `value` that you want?  Is it the anchor text of the link?

We create an interface `Link` with the properties that we want from each link

```
interface Link {
    location: string;
    value: string;
}
```

Then we create a function that extracts all links from an html string and converts them to an array of `Link` objects.

```
function parseLinks( stringHTML: string ): Link[] {
    // create a parser object
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    // turn the string into a Document
    const doc = parser.parseFromString( stringHTML, "text/html" );
    // get all links
    const linkNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // convert from HTMLCollection to array to use .map()
    const linksArray = [...linkNodes];
    // map from HTMLAnchorElement to Link object
    return linksArray.map( element => ({
        location: element.href,
        value: element.innerText,
    }))
}
```

Now you can do whatever with the links from your text

```
const text = `<html><body><a href="C:\Users\K\Documents\docker_command.txt">A.txt </a>
               <a href="C:\Users\Documents\B.txt">B.txt </a>
               <a href="C:\Users\K\Documents\D.txt">D.txt </a>
               <a href="https:\\www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com </a>
  </body></html>`;

const links: Link[] = parseLinks( text );

// can use like this
links.map( ({location, value}) => {
    // do something here
})
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDKgNbIN4ChkHIA2A9gnGMCSAFzIDOYUoA5gNz6EBucRArhDqNmIdrgC%20uXDD4gElasgAOcKPQjoQGegAoGTVgAkAKgFlUQg6OQBKOpowBtALo5OBAPQfkCKBAoocMqq6lDIJABGAFYQ8u4%201IzBatDIALzIIBAA7sgAIgDypgAKIdA6NhyEyF7IYHxQIHUAFijCrMigYCTIQXlkfAC2EODxCIlgyAAmZOnJoQB0KikAYlAkgwDKVix67aIm5gA0yABEkAAeYB7NYINEp7ZVhLUsEJO8RMSY9GMT31oAHIkKYQehzGYIBZvMAAUSIEGG4HoACEAJ7GOAsQFwYY6ADkcHxlXitXGIC40EmMHWg2Qh1QAGESEQEfIqE1ur0oFA4Gi6j0%20OpkAtBnAlBU-iAkkQfgBBHl8uaOBaq2VAkFg5zPTzeMVKZA0jb0syoOVyZokKDwxEjSZchzhaKxMDxPz1RoA7QK3lo0XivQQBFIyZpAB8yB0eGq1VI5AUtGQQdt4AWzT8MCO8WqPH4giTwbtC1AWSgxggVyz1XENhsEik5KSl1DyAABgAeW73MPtiIgtE9oLpiAwNKnRk0AA6AFVQvRJwBpSf9BBDO3zyEYaAAfXGgzFICmCzAV1OYblx6uyHbHjgYezMZj7aHGbHE5nc%20XAxD85Rl7AZ5-iekw3neD6PoQz7IMOo7jlOs7QPOS4rmuyLLv%20Z55P%20163veEH4VBMFjrcYBKPQU6TtkVELPASB9iQGALHuZ5UdkNGIBA9GMXuOFgQQN59lMA43l2RBhq2HC4I2kzqto9iYC4czLOoDi6HUFaTCSuBknATRCigspbi0wC-LJ9D%20hKkbYHGFAcicuYCDW6QRtGLzeDMDAbO8zQdK0fgSDYQA)

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what I need. I need both location and value. :) THank you.